# Ant design input validate to accept only alphabets and special characters but not numbers

Tags: antd

I am new to ant design. I want to validate a field to take only alphabets and special characters but not numbers. This is the approach I have used so far. I am using ant design 4.

```
 <Form.Item
                      label="First Name"
                      name="first_name"
                      rules={[
                        { required: true, message: REQUIRED_ERROR_MESSAGE },
                       {
                        pattern: new RegExp("/^[A-Z@~`!@#$%^&*()_=+\\\\';:\"\\/?>.<,-]*$/i"),
                        message: "field does not accept numbers"
                       }
                      ]}
                    >
                      <Input  />
  </Form.Item>
```

The above approach fails even if a user enters only letters. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try removing the quotes that you currently have around your regular expression like this:

```
pattern: new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z@~`!@#$%^&*()_=+\\\\';:\"\\/?>.<,-]+$/i),
```

here's an example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-rules-ant-design-demo-e0g6c?file=/index.js)